# Self Signed Certificate is always null in Web Api

Tags: c#, ssl, asp.net-web-api, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have spent a complete day on this one and see no way out except to ask my fellows here.

We have a web api which accepts a X509 certificate but following code always gives me null on both localhost and dev server.

below is my code to get the certificate:

```
var certificate = actionContext.Request.GetClientCertificate();
```

I have created an `ActionFilterAttribute` and in it's `OnActionExecuting` I am trying to get client certificate as mentioned above.

Before that I created the certificate using Windows PowerShell following instructions on [this link](https://technet.microsoft.com/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate):

The command I used was this:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "localhost", "atp api" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Certificate was created and I made sure that it is in Trusted Certificates.
Then from my sample client App, I used following code to send the certificate to my Web API:

```
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            var certCollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "localhost", false);
            var cert = certCollection[0];
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://localhost:44308/dk");
            request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "<string xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'>sample string 1</string>";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            //request.ContentType = "application/xml";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream.
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            // Close the Stream object.
            dataStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            store.Close();
```

but when this code was executed in my Web API certificate was null. I thought that it might be because of localhost, and I deployed the web api on development server, the certificate was still null.

I also tried to get the certificate from a specified windows location instead of from store, the result was same.

I have Googled and Googled a lot but nothing helped me.

Comment: I just now followed this step by step guide to create certificate, but results are same:
http://blog.davidchristiansen.com/2016/09/howto-create-self-signed-certificates-with-powershell/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines in web.config in order to force IIS to start the SSL certificate negotiation :

```
<system.webServer>
    <!-- things ... -->
    <security>
        <access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" />
    </security>
    <!-- things -->
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Also, I think this is same as setting the sll settings in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Set `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` property for your `request`:

```
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

[ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method to validate the server certificate. As a result `request` will ignore certificate errors.
If you use .NET Framework less than v4.5 you may set the same callback for 
[ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback(v=vs.110).aspx). If you want you may check custom validation for your certificate.

Comment: I do not want to ignore certificate errors, I want to get the certificate on Server side.

Comment: In this case try to see `HttpWebRequest.ServicePoint.Certificate` property. Detailed example is shown [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepoint(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

you can change SSL Settings in iis to accept the certificate instead of ignoring it.
[image]

Comment: after setting this are you getting forbidden error? or still the certificate is coming as null

Comment: you have to create the certificate with basic permissions, try creating self signed certificate and mention key usage for server authentication and client authentication. you can use open ssl to generate the certificate.  https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/create-the-root-pair.html

Comment: I created the Self signed certificate using IIS, but now I am getting "Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

Comment: The problem is with the creation of the certificate. I think I am not creating the certificate accurately. I have also tried using New-SelfsignedCertificate script for windows. but the problem persist.

Comment: @muhammadkashif Don't forget to import your certificate in Certificate Store (Trusted Root Certification Authorities) for Local Machine or Current User. Then see certificate properties by launching certlm.msc or certmgr.msc. Invalid or untrusted certificate may be the cause of your error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `<security><access sslFlags="SslNegotiateCert" /></security>` to your web config file like Spilarix stated and export a  certificate from the server certifcate and install it and use it for the client so the client has a certificate that is based off the server certificate(and can be validated) but seperate certicate( i know they are both on the same machine).  this should fix your issue

Comment: Certificates.Find method does find the certificate and I successfully added it in the request. but on the server side it is always null.